# Get the type or pass a module like and object in VB

Tags: vb.net, module

I have a logger that works like so:

```
 Dim logger = new Logger(Me)
```

This has the effect of extracting out some information of the entity provided in string format. Unfortunately we have a couple of `Modules` in our code so this naturally does not work.

Is there a way to get the `Type` of a module or basically make it fit without having to pass the information about the module in as a collection of strings.

Comment: Showing the logic in the constructor which extracts the info would be helpful.  What type of parameter does it accept?  Object?

Comment: Correct, it simply checks for null and then extracts the type and namespace as a string, essentially these are the main bits I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType` will return the `Type` object for the current module, but that's very different from the actual instance object when you are in a class, so you would have to handle it differently in the `Logger` constructor.  So for instance, you could detect the difference using an overload, like this:

```
 Public Class Logger
     Public Sub New(consumer As Type)
         Initialize(consumer)
     End Sub

     Public Sub New(consumer As Object)
         Initialize(GetType(consumer))
     End Sub

     Private Sub Iniatialize(consumer As Type)
         ' Extract info from type
     End Sub
 End Class
```

Comment: Cheers, this worked perfect, I simply check if the incoming object is a type and work from there.